# What the best way working with MySQL in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm

Now, for every model in my MVC 3 app I create data class (in separate directory) were store a code which working direct with MySQL:

```
public Models.Inflation Select(int id)
            {
                Models.Inflation inflation = new Models.Inflation();
                MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnectionStringMySQL);
                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT " +
                    "inflation.monthInf, " +
                     "inflation.indexInflation " +
                    "FROM " +
                    "inflation " +
                    "WHERE id=@id " +
                    "ORDER BY inflation.monthInf ASC",
                    connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                MySqlDataReader reader = null;
                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        inflation.ID = id;
                        inflation.Date = DateTime.Parse(reader["monthInf"].ToString());
                        inflation.IndexInflation = decimal.Parse(reader["indexInflation"].ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null)
                        reader.Close();
                    connection.Close();
                }
                return inflation;
            }
```

But this method very tedious (for every Model class I must create Select, Insert, Delete, Edit...). How to improve the development and not using Entity Framework (ORM difficult to connect in my hosting).?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Enterprise libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15104). And in later stage if would like to migrate from MySql to SqlServer datebase you can do this by just changing your connection string.